# Connection Resource Persistency in Parallel AJAX Calls

Tags: php, ajax, json, odbc

Let's say I have a web application whose core is to process student data. There are a number of ways to interface with this data, but let's limit it to these two:

- Students by class
- Students by grade

Through the interface, I can make a single AJAX call to get these students. The SQL statements will differ by interface, but I expect to get a list of students regardless. From there, I want to have multiple AJAX calls made in parallel, one for each student. Specific processing occurs here. This processing is completely independent of the interface--the only requirement is that the input is a student. The processing done is generation of a PDF student report.

Here's what I have done:

- Multiple interfaces making a single AJAX call, both to the same PHP file.
- The PHP file goes through POST and determines which SQL statement to run. Before asking, yes it's prepared and no I don't use POST directly in the query.
- I return an array of students using `json_encode`.
- I iterate over the array of students to generate student-specific documents in parallel by using multiple AJAX calls.

This is fine and dandy and everything is working as intended. The problem is that I'm **opening multiple connections to the database**: once for the initial obtaining of student data, and then **one for every student**. This is horribly inefficient! I had a thought about using [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to encode the connection resource, but the documentation very clearly states that this is **not possible because resources cannot be encoded for JSON**. While ultimately using something like threads would enable me to parallel process the student data without having to return from the initial PHP script, **the server is not configured for pthreads**.

Given this scenario, how does one maintain a single persistent connection resource across multiple parallel AJAX calls? Is it even possible?

Comment: Why not make the call "on demand". Only load the student data when it is requested?

Comment: The call made by the user would be something like "Process data for all 12th graders", in which case all 12th grader student data is requested at once. Previously this was processed one after another, but that can be very slow given the number of students.

Comment: Sounds like you need to make *one* AJAX call to complete a process for all of the 12th graders, not each individually.

Comment: The processing is generation of a PDF student report. If I were to make one AJAX call that document generation would not happen in parallel, and that's the big goal of this project. Edited post slightly to clarify. Gosh, I wish I could use pthreads here. :P

Comment: Your AJAX calls will not be parallel either.

Comment: I disagree. With dummy data I did get AJAX calls in parallel to generate documents. To be extra certain I took timestamps at the start and end of processing for each document. I don't like the fact that I can't do this entirely in PHP. Is it a better idea to put the request to install pthreads for the server?

Comment: If you'll look closely you'll see, because AJAX is *asynchronous*, that the calls may happen close to one another, but never in parallel. Because the data is returned again asynchronously it gives the appearance of parallelism, but it isn't because JavaScript itself is *single-threaded* in all modern browser implementations.